# Python - how to store time series into dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, h5py

I build a parser which converts MIDI song into sequence of note - chord tuples. For each song, it returns list of tuples, where first item is note and second item is set of notes. So resulting data has shape `[(note, {chords})]`, e.g. `[(20, {21, 23}), (30, {22, 24, 26, 28})]`. Notice that chord could be arbitrary long.

I would like to build a dataset from many songs and later pass them into recurrent neural network. **So my question is: What is simplest way to persist this data into file?**

I tried [h5py](http://www.h5py.org) library. Unfortunately, it only works with matrices. Though it would be possible to save each pair like that, it would probably be very inefficient, since length of chord is unlimited.

Comment: Use the pickle library

Comment: @DemetriP Looks nice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pickle it.

```
#Write
import pickle 
x = [(20, {21, 23}), (30, {22, 24, 26, 28})]

with open('pickle.txt','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(x,f)

#Read
with open('pickle.txt','rb') as f:
    y = pickle.load(f)
```